# ES 7.8 forces sorting according to the order of keywords

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an es index with only one title field, and it is a keyword,

```
"mapping": {
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

es api:

```
GET /wyzd_datacenter_202212/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        "term": {
          "title": "hello",
          "boost": 200
        },
        "term": {
          "title": "world",
          "boost": 200
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I use the term query statement to query the keywords "hello" and "world".
If boost is set, it can affect the score, and cannot necessarily achieve the sorting result.

ES defaults to sorting in descending order by _score, and I don't want to use this sorting.

When I search for keywords: "hello" and "world", the result of "hello" appears first, and then the result of "world" appears.

**first:**

……xx hello xx……

……yy hello yy……

Results containing the string "hello"

**then:**

……xx world xx……

……yy world yy……

Results containing the string "world"